# How to execute a series of commands after logging in to a remote server over SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to login to an interactive shell on a server using SSH and, after logging in, execute two commands.

This works: `ssh user1@server -t "cd /home/user2; bash --login"`

None of the following work:

`ssh user1@server -t "cd /home/user2; bash --login -c 'source /home/user2/.bashrc'"`

`ssh user1@server -t "cd /home/user2; bash --login -c source /home/user2/.bashrc"`

`ssh user1@server -t "cd /home/user2; bash --login source /home/user2/.bashrc"`

`ssh user1@server -t "cd /home/user2; bash --login; source /home/user2/.bashrc"`

When I call ssh with the -v flag, I see the following before the ssh session exits:

```
debug1: Sending command: cd /home/user2; bash --login -c "source /home/user2/.bashrc"
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
```

I know this might look odd; I need to login as user1 so that I can use software (legally) that can only be run by user1, but I want to run my personal .bashrc and work in my personal working directory. I can not modify /home/user1/.bashrc. Is there any better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something but in order to achieve the stated goal:

1. Log in as user1
2. Set working directory to the home of user2
3. Source .bashrc from user2

it is enough to say

```
ssh user1@server -t "cd /home/user2; bash --rcfile /home/user2/.bashrc -i"
```

Note that in most cases this would work without the `-i` and without giving the full path to .bashrc:

```
ssh user1@server -t "cd /home/user2; bash --rcfile .bashrc "
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I thought there might be a way to specify an rc file, but I've never needed to do such a thing before.